# Change CSS of current event element

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a hover event in backbone like this:

events:

```
'mouseover .1_select' : 'hover'
'mouseover .2_select' : 'hover'
```

I am then trying to change the same CSS value on the element that has been "hovered over"...

```
  hover: (e) ->
    $(this.el).css('background-position' : '0px -40px')
```

What I need to do is take the event "e" and find our from it which element has been hovered over and update the css on that one only.

At the moment I can see myself writing the function out twice for each class but I do not want to do that - it feels messy. For example the class changes but the property and value I need to change stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$(e.currentTarget)` instead of `$(this.el)` to modify the current target element of an event to which the event was bound. Thanks to jQuery currentTarget is normalized across browsers and you don't have to worry about anything :)

and you can use `this.$el` rather then `$(this.el)` as of `Backbone 0.9` to save some memory and keep your code cleaner